# Implementation of conditional Rotation on ancilla qubit in HHL

Tags: hhl-algorithm

In HHL algorithm, after we have encoded the eigenvalues onto the clock register qubits, we apply conditional rotation on ancilla qubit such that it changes from $|0\rangle$ to: [image]

To achieve this purpose we use $R_y$ gate where $\theta(\lambda_j)=2\arcsin(C/\lambda_j)$ 
 My question is how do we implement this $\theta(\lambda_j)$ function(given we don't know the eigenvalues of matrix $A$) using $U3$ gate on to the quantum computer  so that correct rotation is applied based on the value of $\lambda_j$ ?

I tried to find the answer for this question but could not get much.
I would really appreciate your help here.

Comment: So basically you want to translate $R_Y$ to an $U3$ gate? Here you can find how they are related https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.UGate.html

Comment: I want to know how we implement the function for the angle of rotation that is later provided to $R_y$ gate to apply the rotation